# Kony `MarketPlace ` menu is missing from menu above

Tags: temenos-quantum

I was trying to locate the menu `MarketPlace` from the top menu according to the kony documentation, but it's NOT here.

Answer (score 0):

`MarketPlace` is now named `Forge`. So you can click the `Forge` menu from the top to open the `marketplace`.